# if condition in display tag?

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts, displaytag

I want to display the link if value of row is equal to "GRAND TOTAL" else plain text I tried below snippet but getting error

```
<display:table name="expScoreCardCol" export="true" pagesize="20" sort="list" id="data" requestURI="" class="tablelist">   

     <display:column title="Zone" sortable="true" property="zone"></display:column>              
    <display:column title="Non-HNI Total" sortable="true" property="nonhniTotal"></display:column>   
        <display:column title="Non-HNI Per %" sortable="true" property="nonhniPer"></display:column>   

    <%if(!${data.zone}=="GRAND TOTAL"){ %>       
        <display:column title="Grand Total" sortable="true">   
        <html:link action="/exceptionScoreCardGrandReport.do?zone=${data.zone}"><b>${data.grandTotal}</b></html:link>   
        </display:column>   
        <%} %>   
</display:table>
```

Error:

```
An error occurred at line: 270 in the generated java file
Syntax error, insert "while ( Expression ) ;" to complete DoStatement

An error occurred at line: 282 in the generated java file
Syntax error, insert "while ( Expression ) ;" to complete BlockStatements

An error occurred at line: 288 in the generated java file
Syntax error, insert "else Statement" to complete IfStatement

An error occurred at line: 288 in the generated java file
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block
```

Comment: compile time error..please see above updated post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use scriptlets. Never. Use the JSTL and the EL. And understand that the EL can't be used inside a scriptlet: scriplets contain Java code, and the EL is not Java.

Moreover, the code adds a column if the specific row is not a grand total. This is not what should be done. The column should always be there, but its *content* should change depending on the row:

```
<display:table name="expScoreCardCol" export="true" pagesize="20" sort="list" id="data" requestURI="" class="tablelist">
    <display:column title="Zone" sortable="true" property="zone" />
    <display:column title="Non-HNI Total" sortable="true" property="nonhniTotal" />
    <display:column title="Non-HNI Per %" sortable="true" property="nonhniPer" />
    <display:column title="Grand Total" sortable="true">
        <c:if test="${data.zone != 'GRAND TOTAL'}">       
            <html:link action="/exceptionScoreCardGrandReport.do?zone=${data.zone}">
                <b>${data.grandTotal}</b>
            </html:link>
        </c:if>
    </display:column>      
</display:table>
```